# Registering a new task in C# is not working

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, task

I want to register a new task. My app has admin privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I have tried to find something on the Internet, but there are so many examples that tell me I'm doing it right.
Here's an exception I'm getting:

> COMException was caught Account restrictions are preventing this user
>   from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in
>   times are limited or a policy restriction has been enforced.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007052F)

I don't know why it's not working for me...

Here's my method:

```
private void CreateTask()
{
    using (var ts = new TaskService())
    {
        string computerName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        td.RegistrationInfo.Date = DateTime.Now;
        td.RegistrationInfo.Author = computerName;
        td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "This task is awesome.";

        var trigger = new DailyTrigger(1)
        {
            Enabled = true,
            StartBoundary = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T05:00:00")
        };
        td.Triggers.Add(trigger);

        td.Principal.Id = "Author";
        td.Principal.UserId = computerName;
        td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.Password;
        td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;

        td.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.IgnoreNew;
        td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = true;
        td.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = true;
        td.Settings.AllowHardTerminate = true;
        td.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = false;
        td.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = false;
        td.Settings.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = true;
        td.Settings.IdleSettings.RestartOnIdle = false;
        td.Settings.AllowDemandStart = true;
        td.Settings.Enabled = true;
        td.Settings.Hidden = false;
        td.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
        td.Settings.WakeToRun = false;
        td.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
        td.Settings.Priority = (ProcessPriorityClass) 7;

        td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(Path.Combine(Config.MainDir, "Scripts", "starter.bat"),
                                      workingDirectory: Path.Combine(Config.MainDir, "Scripts")));

        ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("My Task", td);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you've set the password for the user that is to run the task. Based on the exception you are getting, it looks like a password must be specified. What happens when you set the password?

Comment: Was failing it because you needed to add the password? If so, I'll convert my comment to an answer. I originally made a comment because I was just taking a wild guess.

Comment: Yes, it was a password...

Comment: You can add that removing `td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.Password;` also helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the `Principal.LogonType` to `TaskLogonType.Password` you must provide it with a password. So you have 2 options:

1. Remove `td.Principal.LogonType =`TaskLogonType.Password`
2. Specify a password

Answer (score 4):

To "Run whether the user is logged on or not", these lines are not needed:

```
td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.Password;
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("My Task", td);
```

Instead, use this line:

```
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, "someUserId", "somePassword", TaskLogonType.Password);
```

I give credit here: https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/268726